ASP.NET MVC / Web API : how to set a default header with a token, to be used across different controller class?
I'm a beginner in ASP.NET MVC / Web API.
I have an ASP.NET Web API with a login endpoint that returns a token. My endpoint login returns a json with the token and its expiration date. The usage of the token works perfectly in Postman: I can put another endpoint only accessible if there is a token in the header of the request, and I do get a unauthorized response if I don't have the token, and a success response if I have the token.
But I can only get to make this work with Postman.
I also have an ASP.NET MVC application with a login page, and I don't know how to simply add my token in a header for all my future requests.
In my MVC app, I use dependency injection to get a HttpClientFactory in the controller. In Program.cs, I have :
builder.Services.AddHttpClient ("RestoCommandAPI", httpClient =>
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri ("http://localhost:5041/api/");
});

Then in my login controller, I get the token like that :
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Login ([Bind ("Email,Password")] UserInfo userInfo)
{
    userInfo.Id = Guid.NewGuid ().ToString ();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient ("RestoCommandAPI");
        userInfo.Role = UserRoles.User;
        string url = client.BaseAddress + "Authenticate/login";
        //_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", HttpContext.Session.GetString("token"));

        try
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (userInfo);
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync (url, new StringContent (json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Token? token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token> (response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ().Result);

                if (token == null)
                    throw new Exception ("Token null");
                        
                IHeaderDictionary result = new HeaderDictionary(new Dictionary<string, Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues>());

                result.Append("Authorization", new Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues("Bearer " + token.Value));

                HttpContext.Request.Headers.Authorization = result.Authorization;
                // string? tokenValue = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
                // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue ("Bearer", token.Value);

                return RedirectToAction ("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                int statusCode = (int) response.StatusCode;
                return StatusCode (statusCode, response.ReasonPhrase + "\nurl : " + url + "\njson " + json);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return StatusCode (500, e.Message);
        }
    }

    return View (userInfo);
}

It does return 200 when I login. I get the token and try to add it in the HttpContext class. I've also tried others stuff, like settings client.DefaultRequestHeaders, but it's not working because I want to set my authorize header for all HttpClient created by the factory, not only one client.
In another controller, I try to get the token to call a protected endpoint like that :
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Edit (string id, [Bind ("Id,Name,Description,Price,Type,ImageUrl")] Product product)
{
    if (id != product.Id)
    {
        return NotFound ("Product with id " + id + " not found");
    }

    HttpResponseMessage response = null;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string?> query = new Dictionary<string, string?>
            { 
                { "Id", product.Id },
                { "Name", product.Name },
                { "Description", product.Description },
                { "Price", product.Price.ToString () },
                { "Type", product.Type.ToString () },
                { "ImageUrl", product.ImageUrl }
            };

        HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient ("RestoCommandAPI");
        string? tokenValue = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

        if (tokenValue == null)
            return StatusCode (401, "No token found in request header");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue ("Bearer", tokenValue);

        string? requestUri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString (client.BaseAddress + "product/edit/" + id, query);

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage (HttpMethod.Put, requestUri);
        response = client.SendAsync (request).Result;
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest (ModelState);
    }

    if (response == null)
    {
        return StatusCode (500, "Response is null");
    }

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return RedirectToAction (nameof (Index));
    }
    else
    {
        int statusCode = (int) response.StatusCode;
        return StatusCode (statusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
}

It does not work, even if I have logged before, I get the error

No token found in request header

I've googled my issue, but didn't find anything helpful.
For example, I've found this : How to Refresh a token using IHttpClientFactory but I have no clue where their token comes from.
I just want to have Default Header Authentication that I could set in my controllers, I don't understand why it's so difficult.
I probably need to have a DelegatingHandler class, but how to store this token that I get from my login endpoint?
Thank you

Are you using the "old", legacy .NET versions (ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Web API) - or are you on the new, crossplatform .NET Core versions (ASP.NET Core MVC, ASP.NET Core Web API) ? They share a lot - but they're not identical - please be clear and precise in your question, and the tags that you use !

I use cookie, and it works well.
I set my token like that in the logins controller :
CookieOptions options = new CookieOptions ();
options.Expires = token.Expiration;
options.Secure = true;
Response.Cookies.Append ("token", token.Value);

And I set it like that in my controller that calls an endpoint that requiere a token :
string? tokenValue = Request.Cookies["token"];
if (tokenValue == null)
   return StatusCode (401, "No token found in request header");

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue ("Bearer", tokenValue);

